# Need help understanding hash in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, object, hash

I don't really understand this. Can anyone explain it to me? It's from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys.

```
// getFoo is property which isn't enumerable
var my_obj = Object.create({}, { getFoo : { value : function () { return this.foo } } });
my_obj.foo = 1;

alert(Object.keys(my_obj)); // will alert only foo
```

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? What about that behavior is surprising? What did you expect to happen, and what is your reasoning behind that expectation?

Comment: The comment `// will alert only foo` means he expected more than that. He expected `getFoo` to be a key, too.

Comment: I am somewhat new to programming. I understand objects, functions, alerts, the idea of how a hash works (like with ruby). Here it's just a bit overwhelming for me to understand what is going on. For example I don't know what getFoo does. There are a lot of curly brackets so it's confusing to me. I presume that the {} part specifies the prototype. Why does my_obj.foo = 1?

Answer (score 0):

The only defined key is `foo`. By definition, inherited members are not keys. So in the first line you create an object inheriting from the one having `getFoo`. This method `getFoo` is not a key in the inheriting object but in it's parent.

In the reference the emphasis is set on **OWN PROPERTIES**:

> The object whose enumerable own properties are to be returned

In fact, `keys` is an ES5 revival of the less known and less useful `hasOwnProperty()` method, used this way:

```
for (key in obj)
{
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) // exclude inherited keys
    {
        // do something with obj[key]
    }
}
```